# Функция не "видит" глобальные переменные

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В def`ах pif1, pif2 и pif3 указываю global a, b и c соот., и они все между собой работают, но pif4 не хочет их видеть:

```py
import telebot
from cmath import sqrt

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'], content_types=['text'])
def privetstvie(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Бот для счёта a, b (катетов) или c (гипотенузы) в теореме Пифагора\n\nНеобходимо ввести 2 известных числа, а вместо искомого числа отправить команду "Считать"')
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reset', 'count'], content_types=['text'])
def pifna4alo(message):
    pn = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите a:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(pn, pif1)

def pif1(message):
    global a 
    a = message.text
    try:
        a = float(a)
        p1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите b:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(p1, pif2)
    except:
        if(a == '/count'):
                p1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите b:')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p1, pif2)
        elif(a == '/reset'):
            p1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите /reset или /count для сброса:')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(p1, pifna4alo)
        else:
            p1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: выберите "Считать" либо введите значение числа!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(p1, pif1)

def pif2(message):
    global b
    b = message.text
    try:
        b = float(b)
        p2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите c:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(p2, pif3)
    except:
        if(b == '/count'):
            if(a == b):
                p2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: считать можно только одно из чисел!')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p2, pif2)
            else:
                p2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите c:')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p2, pif3)
        elif(b == '/reset'):
            p2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите /reset или /count для сброса:')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(p2, pifna4alo)
        else:
            if(a == '/count'):
                p2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: введите значение числа!')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p2, pif2)
            else:
                p2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: выберите "Считать" либо введите значение числа!')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p2, pif2)

def pif3(message):
    global c
    c = message.text
    global p3
    try:
        c = float(c)
        p3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вычисляю...')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(p3, pif4)
    except:
        if(c == '/count'):
            if(a == c or b == c):
                p3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: считать можно только одно из чисел!')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p3, pif3)
            else:
                p3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вычисляю...')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p3, pif4)
        elif(c == '/reset'):
            p3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите /reset или /count для сброса:')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(p3, pifna4alo)
        else:
            if(a == '/count' or b == '/count'):
                p3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: введите значение числа!')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p3, pif3)
            else:
                p3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: выберите "Считать"!')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(p3, pif3)

def pif4():
    if(a == '/count'):
        a = sqrt(c*c-b*b)
        bot.send_message(p3.chat.id, 'Результат: '+str(a.real)+'\n\nЧтобы использовать бота повторно, отправьте любое сообщение')
    elif(b == '/count'):
        b = sqrt(c*c-a*a)
        bot.send_message(p3.chat.id, 'Результат: '+str(b.real)+'\n\nЧтобы использовать бота повторно, отправьте любое сообщение')
    elif(c == '/count'):
        c = sqrt(a*a+b*b)
        bot.send_message(p3.chat.id, 'Результат: '+str(c.real)+'\n\nЧтобы использовать бота повторно, отправьте любое сообщение')
    else:
        bot.send_message(p3.chat.id, 'КАК ТЫ СЮДА ПОПАЛ?!')

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Edit: вроде решил, но оставляю этот вопрос как память ._.

Comment: Наверное, я чего-то не понимаю. Но где в теле функции pif4  переменные объявлены как глобальные?

Comment: @passant, это же не всегда обязательно. См. мой ответ, например.

Comment: Не рекомендуется править одно-два слова, но не удержался. Совсем уж "`def` не видит" звучит странно. Не видит всё же не сам definition (слово к первой строке относится), а вся функция.

Comment: @Сергей вчера начал Python'ить, поэтому сорян ,_,

Comment: Если решили, то поместите ответ ниже, пожалуйста, с комментарием, чтобы и другие базой знаний могли воспользоваться. Также не забудьте пояснить, что значит "не хочет их видеть":-)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще ничего не знаю о ботах, телеботах и проч. Но мне всегда кажется антипаттерном использовать глобальные переменные поскольку функции их использующие могут принести изменения и отследить это с ростом программы все труднее и труднее. В любом случае, если вы вынесете свои переменные в начало программы и определите их как пустые со значениями `None` и будете потом переопределять в функциях-модификаторах (назовем их так), то все должно сработать и они будут видны на всех уровнях функций.

```py
import telebot
from cmath import sqrt

a = None
b = None
c = None
p3 = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'], content_types=['text'])
.......
```

Я не вижу причин, по которым надо использовать здесь глобальные переменные. Думаю есть смысл написать функции, которые принимают данные значения как входные параметры.

Comment: хм.
учту, спасибо :D
уже дописал по другой схеме, но в будущем попробую эту.

Answer (score 0):

Разбираться в вашем большом коде сложно, что такое "не хочет их видеть" вы не пояснили:-), да и я "ничего не знаю о ботах, телеботах и проч.", но обратите внимание на упрощённый пример ниже на базе вашего кода. Он работает и для `pif4()` (см.комментарии). Надеюсь, поможет. (и да - `global` лучше не использовать, см. объяснение в другом ответе).
И поясните всё же в комменте, что значит "не хочет их видеть":-)

Вообще, `global` в Python работает несколько "необычно", для любителей С, например.

```
def pif1():
    global a
    a = 5
    print('pif1:', a) # Печатает: pif1: 5

def pif2():
    global b
    b = 6
    print('pif2:', a, b) # Печатает: pif2: 5 6

def pif3():
    global c
    c = 7
    print('pif3:', a, b, c) # Печатает: pif3: 5 6 7
    pif4 ()

def pif4():
    print('pif4:', a, b, c) # Печатает: pif4: 5 6 7

pif1()
pif2()
pif3()
```